# Images are not saved after editing Outlook.MailItem HTMLBody

Tags: c#, outlook

I show MailItem.HTMLBody in webBrowser control edit only text and then:

```
reply.HTMLBody = webBrowser.DocumentText;
```

but after sending email images not visible (instead of there are crossed spaces and text: "The linked image can not be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link poinjts to the correct file and location.")

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how the images are embedded in the HTNML page - external images will be just fine. Embedded images (e.g. something like `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR..." />`) do not work in Outlook.